# Combining the Woocommerce Login & Registration Form

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, registration

I am working with a client who is very insistent about his customer experience. He wants to streamline the Woocommerce login and registration forms. Most traditional ecommerce sites do have what seems like a combined form, so I see his point. I haven't seen anything on the market that resembles this. Can this be done?

Dream Scenario #1:
[image: Dream Scenario #1]

2nd and probably more likely scenario
[image: 2nd scenario]

Comment: I always assume that almost everything is possible. Your question is kind of broad and vague at the moment. A screenshot may help as well as any efforts you may have tried.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added images (above) to help describe my issue.

Comment: Scenario 1 looks like a disaster to me. What's there to indicate that a user can sign up if not already a member? Either way, I'm sure it is possible, but Stackoverflow is for answering specific questions and not providing free coding service. If you can make a start and run into problems somewhere you can come back with a more detailed question.

Comment: Not asking for free coding. Now that we got that out of the way, have you seen anything that resembles scenario 2? Is it practical? Educated feedback is what I am after. Not a freebie.

Comment: Ok, but SO isn't for feedback/discussion either. see the FAQ about what is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The second is surely doable, but it doesn't really fit in to the standard [checkout](http://tinyurl.com/ncha3uz) flow.

Comment: I get advice all the time. If you don't want to help, don't. Someone already answered it the question for me anyway.